# How to get just one row from a subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery, query-optimization

I have query with 6 columns and also I want to get the sum of other tables columns.

I want  the result of sub query to be in one row but it repeated.

```
select t.id, t.subject, t.created_at, u.name, l.name as l_name, 
ty.name as t_name
,(select sum(new) from statuses ) as new
,(select sum(open) from statuses) as open
,(select sum(close) from statuses) as close
,(select sum(`delete`) from statuses) as `delete`
 from tickets t 
 left join users u  on u.id=t.user_id
 left join levels l on l.id=t.level_id
 left join types ty on ty.id=t.type_id
```

could you please help me?

[image]

Comment: so what should be in all the other rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` in that,

```
select t.id, t.subject, t.created_at, u.name, l.name as l_name, 
ty.name as t_name
,(select sum(new) from statuses ) as new
,(select sum(open) from statuses) as open
,(select sum(close) from statuses) as close
,(select sum(`delete`) from statuses) as `delete`
 from tickets t 
 left join users u  on u.id=t.user_id
 left join levels l on l.id=t.level_id
 left join types ty on ty.id=t.type_id GROUP BY u.name;
```

Comment: Invalid use of `GROUP BY` unless all the things in the outer select are dependent on u.name.